# Merge two pairs of columns into two columns with their unique values

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
from<-c("Jack","Bill","Jack","Adam")
to<-c("Lary","Jack","Tom","Lary")
from_group<-c("A","A","A","C")
to_group<-c("B","A","D","B")
A<-data.frame(from,to,from_group,to_group)

  from   to from_group to_group
1 Jack Lary          A        B
2 Bill Jack          A        A
3 Jack  Tom          A        D
4 Adam Lary          C        B
```

and I want to merge the first two columns into one with all the unique names and the second two columns into another one with all the resperctive groups like:

```
  names groups
1  Jack      A
2  Bill      A
3  Adam      C
4  Lary      B
5   Tom      D
```

Comment: Why is Jack not in groups A *and* B?

Comment: Sorry he is only A

Comment: I have updated the code respectively. now he is only A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique` with `unlist`

```
unique(data.frame(names=unlist(A[1:2]), groups=unlist(A[3:4])))
#      names groups
#from1  Jack      A
#from2  Bill      A
#from4  Adam      C
#to1    Lary      B
#to3     Tom      D
```

or without the rownames:

```
unique(data.frame(names=unlist(A[1:2], use.names = FALSE),
                  groups=unlist(A[3:4], use.names = FALSE)))
#  names groups
#1  Jack      A
#2  Bill      A
#4  Adam      C
#5  Lary      B
#7   Tom      D
```

or using the name

```
i <- endsWith(names(A), "_group")
unique(data.frame(names=unlist(A[!i]), groups=unlist(A[i])))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library( data.table )
L <- lapply(
  split.default( A, gsub( "_group", "", names(A) ) ),
  setnames, new = c("names", "groups" ) )
#summarise
rbindlist(L)[,.(groups = paste0( unique(groups), collapse = ";")), by = names]

#    names groups
# 1:  Jack      A
# 2:  Bill      A
# 3:  Adam      C
# 4:  Lary      B
# 5:   Tom      D
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pivot_longer` to reshape into 'long' format and use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
A %>% 
   rename_at(vars('from', 'to'), ~ str_c(., "_names")) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_sep = "_", 
       names_to = c("grp", ".value")) %>%
   distinct(names, group)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  names group
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 Jack  A    
#2 Lary  B    
#3 Bill  A    
#4 Tom   D    
#5 Adam  C
```